# Appeared to be logged out after login

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

Started noticing this today. I don't persist data between web sessions.

*Steps to reproduce*

1. Log out; clear all browser-cached data
2. Navigate to a question
3. Log in using OpenID
4. On redirect back to question, the user appears to be logged out (no user toolbar, the *First time here?* bar is present)

   - Navigating to other pages shows user logged in and normal function
   - refreshing page has no effect

---

- *Severity:* mild irritant
- *Reproducibility:* intermittent
- *Workaround:* log out, clear browser data and log in on the start page instead; *update:* or wait a few minutes & refresh
- *Software:* Windows XP; Firefox 3.5.5; [myopenid](https://www.myopenid.com/)
- *Reproducability:* intermittent
- *Uninformed speculation as to cause:* host-side caching side-effect; usage triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We certainly do cache questions for a short period of time, for *anonymous* (not logged in) users. So once you hit a page as anonymous, you have definitely triggered the anon caching for the next (n) anonymous users to hit that exact same page.

But once you're logged in, **that caching no longer applies in any scenario**. Ever.

I would actually argue this is incorrect local browser caching of the page. Have you tried reproducing it in a different browser.. say.. Chrome?

EDIT: as predicted, no repro. I used a virtual machine with XP/Firefox and followed your steps.

EDIT2: ah, I see the problem. Dumb setting mistake on our end. Fixed.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for taking time on this. I was able to reproduce the problem using Chrome (once!) but not, so far, on IE. As I said, it is intermittent. But, given that there aren't others chiming in with _"me too"_, the issue is probably closer to my end.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this today, so I guess that's as good as verified.

Comment: Was this the issue I saw and you disavowed?

Comment: This one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/keep-getting-new-user-banner-on-so

Comment: no, totally unrelated

Comment: Fair enough ;-p I still get that, btw...