# authentication bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid

I have a working so accout, and today I've logged in via openId to serverfault as well, and copied over my account detailes from so.

I can login to serverfault with no problems. However, when I visit my own question https://serverfault.com/questions/88618/lighthttpd-fastcgi-php-phpinfo-crashes, I'm logged out. When I follow whichever other link within serverfault, I'm logged in back.

The only place where I'm counted as guest is on my question page.

Comment: Possibly related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31064/appeared-to-be-logged-out-after-login

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a local caching problem with your browser.

Once you're logged in, server caching is no longer used.

EDIT: I see the problem. Dumb mistake on our end. Fixed.